# Unable to shelve changes in VS2012 for TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are using TFS2010 (for source control only), and until recently everyone was using VS2010. Our developers just installed VS2012.

Pulling down code works fine in Visual Studio. When you go to "Pending Changes" in Team Explorer, we are seeing `TF201072: A user or group could not be found. Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type definition have been added to Team Foundation Server.`, twice, at the top. We can still check-in code from VS - seems this error is ignored.

However, we are unable to shelve changes - when you attempt to shelve, the same error comes up in a popup, and the shelveset is not saved.

We can shelve using the command prompt (`tf shelve`), and can still shelve using VS2010, so it doesn't seem to be a permission issue. Also, the TFS administrator is not seeing the error message, and can shelve from VS2012 with no error.

Any thoughts as to what could be causing VS to error out here? We've tried clearing out the TFS cache, creating a new workspace, and gone over every option we could find in Visual Studio.

Comment: What else did you guys do?  Specifically, did *anything* happen on or to the TFS server such as moving it...

Comment: @ChrisLively Nope, no server changes at all. We simply installed VS2012 on our developer machines. Still connecting to the same TFS server, the same collection, same project, using the same Windows credentials. We upgraded one specific solution to VS2012, but that only affected that one particular SLN file. The problem is global to any of our solutions.

Comment: Well.. that is truly weird.  I've done several upgrades to VS2012 while hitting TFS2010 with zero issues.  The error you are receiving should only be happening if the server itself is having a hard time sync'ing credentials with AD... well, that and a problem in a config file on the TFS server itself.

Comment: @ChrisLively Is there maybe a way to refresh the credentials on the TFS server? We rebooted the server already, but if there's some way to maybe give it a little kick, that would be worth a try.

Comment: See if this helps:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emmamou/archive/2009/03/13/a-case-study-on-tfs-identity-replication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried many different stuff from web sites and non of them helped. Finally find the solution for this. Follow these to make it work:

1) Create temporary AD User

2) You will need to transfer all old user configuration into a new temporary account. If you are OK with using the temporary account you may just keep it and get rid of old account. Go into the machine that TFS is installed and Run this command: `TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain:mydomain /todomain:mydomain /account:oldAccount /toaccount:temporaryAccount`

(TFSConfig is in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server XX.0\Tools\`)

3) If you don't want to use temporary account you will need to convert from temp account to your old account. To do that run the same command wit changing the user names:
`TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain:mydomain /todomain:mydomain /account:temporaryAccount /toaccount:oldAccount`

That's  all you need to do.