# Project administrator cannot run workitem query

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

TFS team project administrator not able to run work item query, when tried through the web browser, page shows the error:

**TF401349: An unexpected error has occurred, please verify your request and try again**

When tried using Visual Studio 2015, the below error:

**TF201072: A user or group could not be found. Verify that the users and groups used in your work item type definition have been added to Team Foundation Server.**

Event log in the application server shows the below event error:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): error="600047";%:RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be alidated.   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)**

I am using TFS 2015 update 2.

Note: Same project other users can view normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is something wrong with that user account, although this user is already part of a TFS group, but he still can't access TFS work items. Maybe there is some snag in the **TFS identity synch service**, and it's usually related to a specific collection.

**Attaching and re-attaching the collection** will force a refresh of the identity synch data, and will usually resolve this kind issue.

If above is sitll not work.There are also  many other articles on the web which help determine the root cause:

- You can check whether built-in records were missing in table
  TFSIntegration..tblsubscription. Refer to the link below for more
  details: [A case study on TFS identity replication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emmamou/2009/03/13/a-case-study-on-tfs-identity-replication/#commentmessage)
- Another option is check if the SID of service account is correct.
  Replace SID if not, you can refer to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3403d10-a591-43f2-bfa2-f14750755193/tf30177-team-project-creation-failed?forum=tfsadmin) for the steps.
- Also take a look at the solution of this similar
  error:[Unable to shelve changes in VS2012 for TFS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882136/unable-to-shelve-changes-in-vs2012-for-tfs2010)

Comment: thanks for the reply, the Identity synch service is running sucessfully, but i have seen failures with the Work Item Tracking Integration Synchronization. I guess this could be the root cause. Since the user is able to access other part, only the Work item query part is not working. the error listed :
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Constants' with unique index 'IX_Constants__String_RemovedDate'

Comment: i have confirmation from the user that he is able to access now. I guess the issue was with the Identity sync and over the weekend the sync ran and the user is good now.

Comment: Glad to hear the issue solved. If the issue is related to **Work Item Synchronization** . This may also effect some other people.  It does not meet your situation.