# TF201072: A user or group could not be found

Tags: tfs

We were given a backup of a collection in TFS 2010 that was turned over to us. I loaded it and I can see the projects in TFS, when I try to access the projects i get the below error. I currently have collection admin rights and project admin rights. Any ideas on how to correct this.

> TF201072: A user or group could not be found. Verify that the users
>   and groups  used in your work item type definition have been added to
>   Team Foundation  Server.

I thought originally that the AD sync didn't work when i added myself to the admin groups so I detached and reattached the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly..

Well, detached and reattached the collection may not do the force sync. You could try to kick it off: [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)

Also check if you had a bad login. Clear the credentials cache relogin  and restarting the **Team Foundation Background Job Agent**  service.

You could also try the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882136/unable-to-shelve-changes-in-vs2012-for-tfs2010) with similar error which may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks this helped.